# Javascript: Convert code string and back

Tags: javascript, string, ecmascript-6, type-conversion

Suppose that I have this code:

```
var cfg = {
  config: {
    fields: {
      name: {
        type: 'text'
      },
      age: {
        type: 'number'
      }
    },
    actions: [
      {
        label: 'Print',
        cb: (model) => {
          console.log(model);
        }
     }
   ]
  },
  data: {name: 'Jhon', age: 23}
}
```

And I want to convert it to a string (to let a user edit it) and then convert it back to executable code, any idea in how to achieve this?

I tried with `JSON.stringify` and `JSON.parse` but that will of course strip the functions. `.toString` returns `"[object Object]"`, iterating on the object and call `.toString` when the values is a string, function or number is a possibility, any other idea?

Comment: Do you really need your users to edit functions?

Comment: Yes I need to, it is a tutorial on how to use and co figure UI componenti, so I need the user to write some code and execute it

Comment: Then you should start with a string, not with an object. Don't convert back and forth, only use `eval` on strings. For the initial code, put it in a string literal or load it from a file.

Answer (score 5):

The [Function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function) constructor takes code as string, so does [eval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval) and a couple other. However, if in any way avoidable, do not convert code to string and backwards because of security concerns, ability to debug and a lot of other issues you can run into when doing so.

Converting code to a string is slightly annoying, because you need to make sure you don't redeclare variables and everything in the new context is syntactically correct, e.g. note that `obj`'s `f` property is again named in the declaration, because it is later given to `eval` which places it in the global scope where it needs a name.

```js
let obj = { f: function f() { let stuff = "hi"; console.log("hi"); } };
let code = obj.f.toString();
console.log(code);
eval(code);
f();
```

Note that [JSON.stringify](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) has an optional `replacer` parameter which can be used to customize the process.

I will again highly advise to avoid any code to/from string conversions when possible, in all normal cases this is not needed and should not be done.

Comment: In our case is a tutorial in a controlled environment, so no security issues

Comment: I have `a ={f: converter.setOption('tables', true)};present=a.f.toString()` and get `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'toString' of undefined`

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate around that object and set it to inputs elements, like this

```
for (var key in cfg.config.fields) {
   console.log(key, cfg.config.fields[key].type);
   console.log(key, cfg.data[key],'data');
   console.log('<input type="'+cfg.config.fields[key].type+'" value="'+cfg.data[key]+'">')
}
```

Comment: Yes that is the way I'm following... It is actually a bit more complex as we don't know the structure but a recursive function made the trick. I'll post it soon.

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution I came up with:

```
const toString = (code) => {
  if(Array.isArray(code)){
    return code.map(item => toString(item));
  }
  else if(typeof code == 'object'){
    let tmp = {};
    Object.keys(code).forEach(key => {
      tmp[key] = toString(code[key])
    });
    return tmp;
  }
  else{
    return code.toString().split('\n').join('').replace(/ +(?= )/gmi, '');
  }
};
```

This will iterate recursively across all the properties in a random JS structure (an object containing objects and arrays) an return the corresponding structure containing strings, you can then use `JSON.stringify` to get the actual string.

After the user edited it, it is executed with:

```
eval(`(${string})`);
```

As noted by other, be careful using `eval`, it can be dangerous (an interesting article is https://www.nczonline.net/blog/2013/06/25/eval-isnt-evil-just-misunderstood/)